# Error while trying to extract jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to extract a jar file using the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>jar xf C:\Users\...\MyJar.jar
```

but get the error:

```
java.io.IOException: META-INF : could not create directory
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:953)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:877)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:263)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

What can it be solved?

Comment: I just ran into this. In my case, something has already created a file at <i>META-INF\LICENSE</i> and now something else is trying to create a directory at <i>META-INF\license</i>. I'm working with a shaded jar I built from Linux .. and I'm hitting this now when decompressing in Windows. My Windows shell is case insensitive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you don't have write permissions in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin`.

Try uncompressing it in a different folder or open a console as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like permission issue.

Try extracting the jar file using WinRAR or 7-zip. you can right click on jar file and select extract to (Where you have write permission) .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its a permission issue . Please check that :

1) You have read/write permission in that folder you are trying to extract to .
2) The folder is write protected

Try to copy that to a different directory and try to extract the jar .